# Xubuntu messed up (by me) -> best way to start fresh?

Tags: xubuntu, remote-desktop

I have Xubuntu 20.04 installed on a little headless server. I connect to it via ssh and XRDP.

Before landing on XRDP I have tried many many combinations of VNC, forwarding X, X2Go... now I have installed xrdp and it seems the best.

My issue is that I believe that during all that trial and error I messed some things up. These are the things that don't work particularly well

- on connection (via XRDP) I get an error message "system program problem detected" with the only options of ignoring and report problem, which does nothing
- whenever I launch the "software updater" i get a message "you stopped the check for updates"
- when software updater WAS working, it wouldn't upgrade my firmware (and I wasn't successful with fwupdmgr either)
- conky always worked "sketchy"
- when I look at logs for some of these issues two things keep coming up: DBus (?) and policykit (?) issues

---

I could try and fix everything one by one, but I am not sure I have the knowledge to do a great job.

Given that I would like to upgrade the SSD the system is on to a larger one, I was thinking I should just re-install xubuntu from scratch on that disk and pass my personal data manually. But I am unsure about just copying my home folder, as I believe there are errors in files there everywhere.

---

what would you recommend me to do? Is there a way to "reinstall xubuntu" over itself without losing my data? Or is re-installation on a new drive the best course of action?

Comment: Hi. Both apt-get update and upgrade work well - the system is up to date. Everything seems to be working correctly on terminal, the issues are all on the X

Comment: Based upon your estimate of your own skills, I recommend that you backup your data and reinstall. Some of the problems that you describe may have quite easy solutions, but others may not. Also, it seems that you don't really want to share the level of detail that we need to give you more specific troubleshooting and repair advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy only the data files like pictures, videos, music, text all them directories. To a safe backup then abandon the install for new drive install. This will leave out all those configurations that may have errors in them. Do not even have to copy to backup if you purchase external USB case or a dongle that connects to the SATA then via a USB connector to the computer. Then you can simply put old drive in case or connected to dongle and copy the files as needed.

Comment: thank you - so you would also recommend a new install vs trying and fixing the current one ?

Comment: The time it takes to do install vs hours more wasted on broken one. I would go with the new, though not being perfect, I have indeed done the waste more time, many times, I'm never getting that back .... Your call some of the time it pays off and you gain some good knowledge from doing it, others it is useless.